# Unable to install Odoo 12 Community Edition using docker compose file on an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, odoo

I am getting an "Internal Server Error" when trying to install Odoo 12 Community Edition on an AWS EC2 instance using a docker-compose file. My EC2 instance uses Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1031-aws x86_64) operating system, Docker version 18.09.0 and docker-compose version 1.23.2.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:12.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:
```

I can see the containers being created as is evidenced by the following output of the "docker ps -a" command:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES

64e271db9565        odoo:12.0           "/entrypoint.sh odoo"    2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:8069->8069/tcp, 8071/tcp   ubuntu_web_1

10b3198e3230        postgres:10         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          5432/tcp                           ubuntu_db_1
```

Moreover, the "docker-compose config" command returned the following output:

```
services:
  db:
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: odoo
      POSTGRES_USER: odoo
    image: postgres:10
    volumes:
    - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata:rw
  web:
    depends_on:
    - db
    image: odoo:12.0
    ports:
    - 8069:8069/tcp
    volumes:
    - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo:rw
    - /home/ubuntu/config:/etc/odoo:rw
    - /home/ubuntu/addons:/mnt/extra-addons:rw
version: '2.0'
volumes:
  odoo-db-data: {}
  odoo-web-data: {}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check the container logs? It should show you the backtrace that caused the internal server error.

Comment: On checking the container logs it appeared that the database was not initialized.